# Limit available printers for a MS Word Document, or define a "Default printer" in a particular document

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, printer, limited-access

I've a lot of printers (or specific printer's queue with particular setup for each queue) configured on my PC. Each have a unique "Printer Queue Name".

I work with a software which generates Word Document, using "Mergefields". At print time, i have to select manualy the desired printer, and sometimes, it's not the good one, leading to paper wast, lose of time, unefficient process.

My main software is not able to bind document printing to the desired printer queue.

Do MS Word have a fonctionnality (with VBA or "Mergefield") which help me to limit the list of available printers ? At best it would limit to a SINGLE print queue ! To reiterate, can i define through MS Word a specific "Default Printer" based on an info i can set IN my MS Word Document (with VBA or Mergefield...).

Guys, help me to earn time, money, and avoid paper wasting !

Comment: So do you want Word to only have one printer, or do you have a certain printer for different steams of files?

Comment: I want to filter/limit availables printers at print time, relying on something i can store in my "MS Word pattern document". Imagine an host with 3 availables printers, A,B,C . "Invoice.doc" must be printed on "B". At print time, MS Word will list all 3 printers. Another "Order.doc" must be printed on "A".